# IIS smtp server send mail to a number

Tags: smtp, office365, lotus-notes, lotus

In our active directory all the users have a unique number, we migrated from lotus notes to office 365 and when we try to send a scanned document from a printer/scanner we used to use a lotus notes smtp server. We were able to send the mail to the unique user number. So to make this a little bit more clear, the mail was leaving from the printer/scanner towards the lotus notes smtp server and the recipient address was for instance 1010, if we look into the messagetrace of lotus notes we see rcpt 1010, not rcpt 1010@domain.com. The lotus notes server was able to translate the 1010 to an actual user in their domino directory. Now we want to remove the lotus notes server from our network and replace it with a IIS smtp server.
If we try the same, the mail goes into the badmaildirectory, because 1010 is not a valid emailaddress. This is logical to me. We also tried ldap, but this does not work. If there is a possibility to always add a domain to the recipient, this would be a solution.
Is there a way we can make this work? Maybe through a mail gateway or something? Anyone have an idea?

Comment: The domain suffix is optional for native Notes mail routing, and (in theory, at least) it should be optional for SMTP mail delivery, too. The key, though, is that the system must recognize your unique user numbers as legitimate aliases for the users. In your Domino system, you must have those numbers entered into the ShortName field, or as an alternate entry in theFullName field.

Comment: I think they key for you is that you need to make your configuration work so that 1010@domain.com works, and you have to make sure that your SMTP server is configured to forward all messages addresssed to non-local @domain.com users to your Offfice365 system. With Domino, you would do that with the SmartHost setting. I don't know what the appropriate setting is for the IIS SMTP server. But BTW - this question is really more apporpriate for ServerFault than for StackOverflow.